# CSS3 positioning and misunderstanding usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time on this one: [HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/m3fU3/)

As you can see in my `JSFIDDLE` as you hover on the image you can see scrolling caption. My problem now, how can I `show` the scrolling caption when the image is `CLICKED`? and likewise when i clicked the other image when it is inactive the scrolling caption will hide.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: I hover the image, I see the caption. But if I click the image, won't I be taken to a different page? I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible without the use of Javascript, but you need to rewrite your HTML a bit.

What you basically do, is to create a hidden checkbox or radiobutton, which overlays the image. Then you can use CSS to check for its `:checked` state, and hide/show content accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="item">
   <label for="toggle" class="item__toggle"></label>
   <input id="toggle" type="radio" name="item__togglers" class="item__check">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics" alt="">
   <figcaption class="item__caption">Hello world</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.item__caption {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        left: 0;
}

/* TOGGLE MECHANISM */
.item__toggle {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.item__check {
    display: none;
}

/* THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS */

.item:hover .item__caption,
.item__check:checked ~ .item__caption {
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

**JS FIDDLE**
I created a very basic jsfiddle to demonstrate the functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/6vUVP/1/

Comment: Would downvoters please explain what's wrong with my answer? As far as I can tell, it solves the answer as described.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. BTW, I'm not the one who down vote your answer. all your answer are correct and I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
   http://jsfiddle.net/m3fU3/4/
   Check now..

i think this is what you wanted?
Just replace the *hover* in the css with *active*,for **active** is on layman's terms ,the click picker on css.

Example:

```
 .cap-left:active figcaption{
      left: 0;
      }
```

**Option 2:** 
You can use **javascript** onclick functionality:

HTML:

```
<img  src="image.png" id="image1" onclick="zoomImage()"/></a>
```

JS:

```
function zoomImage(){
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('image1').zoom=2;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: You can also use jquery...

Comment: -ve voters,care to comment on what's wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. option 1 is near to my expected result. What i really want to say is when I click the image then the caption will remain visible on that image. please see the answer of @Nix its similar to that. anyways thank you! 

BTW, im not the one who voted down your answer.

Comment: how can I use this using `JQuery.addClass Function` when my class is `.cap-left:active figcaption`?